# Crashes when in simulator when button pressed

Tags: iphone, debugging, button, crash, ios-simulator

I have 3 views and the first view has a motion background (sequence of pictures), music, and two buttons. When I push either button it crashes. I have a feeling its a memory problem but I'm not sure how to fix this. I'm rather new to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

What's in the Xcode log when you run the app under the debugger?

Are your buttons hooked up to IBActions? If so, what do they do? Put a breakpoint on them in the debugger and watch what happens, where does it crash?